# Symfony4.4: Create distinct URL for login (admin/user) (owasp recommandation)

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, distinct, user-roles

I'm using symfony4.4.28. I want to create 2 distinct path for authentication:

For Admin Role: --> mysite.com/admin/login

For User Role: --> mysite.com/user/login

Any suggestions?

Note that is an OWASP recommendation for more security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create two different firewall in security.yml I supposed.